# Simple Linear regression why i am predictin y values when i am not using?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I leraning from a online course and i am not understanding why we using predict on y_pred when we are not using anywhere

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
print(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `y_pred` are the prediction outputs. It's presumably up to you to use them now.

Comment: you should compare `y_test` and `y_pred` to see how good your fit is. Calculate R, R^2 and some error value. Also, please read the how to ask, as your question currently is very far from a programming question and about a code you did not write.